# Node zip-folder Path error

Tags: node.js, path, zip

So my project structure looks like:

root

- app.js
- node_modules
- package.json
- Spreadsheets

I want to use the zip-folder module to zip the contents of the folder spreadsheets. The code provided is:

```
var zipFolder = require('zip-folder');

zipFolder('/path/to/the/folder', '/path/to/archive.zip', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('oh no!', err);
    } else {
        console.log('EXCELLENT');
    }
});
```

My code is:

```
   zipFolder('./Spreadsheets/', './', function(err) {
     if (err) {
       console.log('oh no!', err);
     } else {
       console.log('EXCELLENT');
     }
   });
```

because I want to save the zip in the root folder. However I get the following error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open './'
at Error (native)
```

I believe this has something to do with paths but am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed zip file name. Working code looks like this:

```
 zipFolder('./Spreadsheets/', './Spreadsheets.zip', function(err) {
     if (err) {
       console.log('oh no!', err);
     } else {
       console.log('EXCELLENT');
     }
   });
```

PS Welcome to Stack Overflow!